# Prove that set $\mathbb{S}$ forms group under matrix multiplication

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I have give the following set to prove that $$\mathbb{S} = \left \{\begin{bmatrix}  1&0 \\   0&1  \end{bmatrix},\begin{bmatrix}  0&-1\\   1&-1  \end{bmatrix},\begin{bmatrix}  -1&1\\   -1&0  \end{bmatrix}  \right \}$$ forms group under matrix multiplication.
I already know how to check if the certain set obey the axioms in order to be a group, but following set has finite number of elements(matrices). I was struggling to proceed with this example. Your advice would be appreciate.

Comment: Why do you think it is a problem that the set is finite? This makes things easier ...

Comment: You only have to check very, **very** few products... In fact, you should know that *if* this set is a group then it is a cyclic one. Much easier still...

Comment: @WardBeullens, you mean i just need to multiply first element with second one and check if it obey the axioms to be group?

Comment: If this is a group, then it must be a cyclic group of order $3$. Just pick a non-identity element and compute its powers (both of them must generate the entire group), then the group axioms become obvious.

Comment: @JFC In other words you just take the middle matrix $M$ and check that $M^2$ is the third matrix and $M^3$ is the identity. If that holds then the set is a group.

Comment: Seems that i have overestimated the problem, just as you said on the comments i needed to pick any two elements from the set and check for axioms.